# i want to make custom toolbar but when i open my app my app crashes

Tags: android, android-studio

this is my toolbar xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbarxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com /apk/res/android"    
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="#affa0505"
android:elevation="4sp"
android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:popupTheme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
app:titleTextColor="#fff"
>
```

and i have added this file into mainActivity

```
        <include layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        />
```

and this is my menu file

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 tools:context="com.example.shery.youtubevideodownloader.Main2Activity">
 <item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:icon="@drawable/share"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/action_settings" />
</menu>
```

and this is my java file

```
      toolbar =  findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main2, menu);
    return true;
}
```

and the error is

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.shery.youtubevideodownloader, PID: 25483
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.shery.youtubevideodownloader/com.example.shery.youtubevideodownloader.SplashScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.hide()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2957)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.hide()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.shery.youtubevideodownloader.SplashScreen.onCreate(SplashScreen.java:17)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7183)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2910)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at     com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

I/Ads: App measurement is starting up, version: 13001

i dont know what is the mistake on my project when i open my app my appp crashes and i want to add tool bar

and this my spalshScreen Code

```
package com.example.shery.youtubevideodownloader;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
      this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREENWindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);,   
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);





    Thread th = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();

            try {
                //You Can Increase Or Decrease The Timing Of Splash Screen By Adding the number on sleep.
                sleep(2000);
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                finish();

            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    th.start();


}
```

}

Comment: The problem is in `SplashScreen`, not `MainActivity`, or `Main2Activity` (whichever it's called).

Comment: can i share spalsh screen file with you

Comment: after adding tool bar code the problem will come on spalsh screen andd this problem is not coming before adding toolbar

Comment: Sure, you can [edit] your question to add it.

Comment: share your splashscreen code

Comment: Did you change your app's `theme` in the manifest, when you added the `Toolbar`? You might include the manifest in your edit, too.

Comment: may be you hide your toolbar before setSupportActionBar(toolbar). so please check your code and if you get further problems then share your activity where you hide actionbar

Comment: how to add toolbar in menifesr

Comment: i have  change theme in style and on the menifest the theme will automatically changed

Comment: i have hide my default tool bar before

Comment: yes i have comment the hide code and again app crashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `onCreate()` you call

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

why? Remove it.  
You shouldn't have the default `ActionBar` since you want a Toolbar..  
If your theme in `styles.xml` is like

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

change it to:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Comment: i have change it to no action bar

Comment: again app crashes

Comment: Then remove getSupportActionBar().hide();

Comment: <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

Comment: i have  remove getsupportActionBar.hide; but app again crashes

Comment: let me comple it

Comment: Also clean and recompile if necessary.

Comment: i saw a youtube video and i implemented the code same as video but got error

Comment: because i have to remove getSupportActionBar().hide from the spalsh screen and my app works fine

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREENWindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);,   
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
        },2000);
}

}
```

Comment: before adding toolbar the app works fine after adding toolBar code it crashes

Comment: @Sherry Where you have added the toolbar ? Is it in Splash Screen? because from your code it seems that you don't want toolbar in splash screen and trying to hide that by calling  getSupportActionBar().hide(); but this gives you NLP Exception as toolbar is not yet set. If you want Toolbar in your splash screen then call setSupportActionBar(toolbar).

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you want to hide toolbar then why are you adding toolbar to your xml?

Anyway to get things work, do these:

1. In your toolbar.xml place a space between Toolbar and xmlns.
2. Add id to your `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`in toolbar.xml

> ```
> <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com /apk/res/android"    
> android:id="@+id/toolbar"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>     android:background="#affa0505"
>     android:elevation="4sp"
>     android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
>     app:popupTheme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
>     app:titleTextColor="#fff"
>     >
> ```

3. Remove `android:id="@+id/toolbar"` from include tag.
4. Change your SplashScreen code, you need to call `setSupportActionBar` method before hiding toolbar:

> ```
>      requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
>
>           this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREENWindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);,
>
>         setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
> setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
> getSupportActionBar().hide();
> ```